# Indexing hash key and value in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I tried following [this tutorial.](https://medium.com/better-programming/two-ways-of-finding-the-element-that-occurs-the-most-in-an-array-with-ruby-7fb484ea1a6d)
I want to find the instances of highest frequencies within my Hash. Code:

```
class Dice
    def roll
        line = gets.chomp!.split(" ")
    
        en = line[0].to_i
        em = line[1].to_i
        outcomes = Array.new
        for n in 1..en
            for m in 1..em
                prob = n + m
                outcomes << prob
            end
        end
        outcome_count = Hash.new(0)
        outcomes.each { |outcome| outcome_count[outcome] += 1}

        most_frequent = Array.new
        # adding key with highest frequency
        most_frequent << outcome_count.sort_by { |outcome, value| value }.last[0]
    
        count = 1

        while outcome_count.sort_by{ |outcome, value| value }.reverse.values_at(count) == 
        outcome_count.sort_by{ |outcome, value| value }.reverse.values_at(count-1)
            most_frequent << outcome_count.sort_by{ |outcome, value| value }.reverse[count]
            count += 1
        end
        puts most_frequent
    end
end

d = Dice.new
d.roll()
```

I can find the highest instance as shown when adding the first key.
However, I want to compare the values (and just the values) so that I can *also* add keys that have the same value as the key with the highest value. Whenever I try to access the value of the key, I just get both the key (the outcome, or combined score of rolling two dices) *and* the frequency of the outcome.

The way I tried to access the value was with this code:

`outcome_count.sort_by{ |outcome, value| value }.reverse.values_at(count)`

But even though I'm finding the right key, I still get both the outcome and the frequency of the outcome as returned value.
Am I using the wrong datastructure (Hash)? How can I solve this?

Read: I am super fresh in Ruby and I would like as much explanation as possible!

Comment: To obtain the 3 keys having the greatest frequency in the array `arr = [1,3,4,3,2,1,1,5,4,2,1,2]`, in order of decreasing frequency, you can write `arr.tally.max_by(3, &:last).map(&:first) #=> [1,2,4]`. Here `arr.tally #=> {1=>4, 3=>2, 4=>2, 2=>3, 5=>1}`. See [Enumerable#tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally) and [Enumerable#max_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by). `tally` made its debut in Ruby v2.7. `arr.tally.max_by(3, &:last)` is shorthand for `arr.tally.max_by(3) { |a| a.last }`, where `a` is a key-value pair `[k,v]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thank you, but it could be more than 3. It has to add outcomes based on frequency. I did however solve the issue, it was a case of misunderstanding return type. The returned key-value pair was an array, I believe, and not a single int as I initially believed. Adding another indexing was enough to solve the issue, akin to /.reverse[0][1]/

Comment: `3` (and `[1,3,4,3,2,1,1,5,4,2,1,2]`) are just an example. `3` could be any integer between `1` and `arr.size`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland but, without analyzing thoroughly, wouldn't 3 be a magic number that I would have to get someway? And I don't see any immediate way to find 3 without comparing values of the k-v pairs, which again makes it faster to just add them to the array while doing the comparing?

Comment: However, would you like to add the solution (even if it doesn't answer exactly my weird question!) to this question, so I can add it as a verified answer? :)